# Keeping icons at bottom of post with dynamic text in box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a box that contains the post content which is text. What happens is if the content "overflows", the box gets bigger, but the icons push out of the box. What I want to do is keep them as a solid location. Here's what I see

[image]

The comment, delete, and likes count is off to the side. And here's what I want it to look like, even when there is more content

[image]

Here's the CSS for the box

```
.main-content{
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

And the icons

```
.fa-comment {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 67px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #69f;
}
.likes{
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.fa-heart-o{    
    transition: 0.5s;
    margin-top: 60px;
    color: #FF6699;
    font-size: 24px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-heart{  
    transition: 0.5s;
    margin-top: 60px;
    color: #FF6699;
    font-size: 24px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-trash-o {   
transition: 0.5s;
    margin-top: 67px;
    color: #ABA9A9;
    font-size: 24px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.icons{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}
```

I'm not sure if I'd do this with CSS or JS, but any help would be great.

Comment: providing fiddle for this situation will make this a lot easier.

Comment: Here's the issue http://jsbin.com/liqudiqa/1 and what a normal box icons should look like http://jsbin.com/lolipiku/1 @Yaje

Comment: Or give us the HTML... but it looks like you are trying to float too many things, why not try to fix a few elements or block display your divs.

Comment: HTML is also in the demo. Which is in the above comment @upful

Comment: I can't make head or tails of that js bin... can you add the HTML to the post, those classes are easier to follow than `#DIV_1`

Answer (score 1):

You can Add clearfix after comments block.
For example:

```
<div class="main-content">
... 
Your images and text
...
<div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>


<style>
.clearBoth{
 clear:both;
}
</style>
```

You can use my block-style: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y49D2/3/)

Comment: Can you supply a fiddle? I can't seem to get it working

Answer (score 1):

You might be over-complicating this.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6HSB/17/

As a rule of thumb, work on scoping out your DOM first, and make it clean and neat.

HTML:

```
<div class="comment">
  <div class="comment-content">
    <div class="image-holder">
      <img src="">
    </div>
    <p>The comment text would go here. It could be really short or really long and it won't matter because this is ambiguous to size. It will resize automatically and clear the space below it because that's how this works when you keep your structures simple and float elements where needed while providing a clearfix to push things down when needed.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="comment-actions">
      <a href class="likes">0 Likes</a>
      <a href class="comment"><span class="fa fa-comment">comment</span></a>
    <a href class="delete"><span class="fa fa-trash-o">delete</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Once you've got a nice DOM setup, create as little style as you need to get your basic structure.

CSS: (LESS OR SCSS for simplicity)

```
body {
    background: #888;
}

.comment {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    .comment-content {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        .image-holder {
            float: left;
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
    }
    .comment-content:after {
        content: ".";
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        visibility: hidden;
        line-height: 0;
        height: 0;
    }

    .comment-actions {
        text-align: right;
        a {
            display: inline-block;
            // you'd want to tweak the styles here. but it should not require much.
        }
    }
}
```

After this, you can customize it to meet your exact needs, but I find it easiest to work in steps like this to get your desired placement before adding any visual context.

Cheers!